# How to create folder in root of storage Android

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm new at this.

Telegram, Whatsapp, Vk, Aliexpress - All this apps can write they folders in /Storage/emulated/0

How can I create my folder in this place for Android 5...10?

When I try to use File("/storage/emulated/0/", myfile) - it doesn't work.

Please, can anyone give some mini example how can I create my files in storage

Comment: No that will not work. That does nothing. Folders you should create with File:mkdirs().

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't written any code, I can't tell you what you're doing wrong. But [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) is something that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare permissions on your manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After that you can simply use this to create your folder.

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + 
    "folderName";

    File directory = new File(path);
    directory.mkdirs(); // It returns a boolean you can use it to check if your folder 
                        // was created.
```

Comment: I create new project in AndStd with legacy support, add ur code. Add both manifest permission. After app open I approve right to storage. But directory.mkdirs() == false. And no folder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create Folders inside the External Storage too.
But, keep in mind that you cannot use emulated/0 because it is different for different devices.

```
File path = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Folder/");
if(!path.exists()){
        boolean k = path.mkdirs();
    }
```

Although, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated as of API29. So You can use getExternalDir() too.